# Electron Desktop Notifications not displaying on windows 10

Tags: notifications, windows-10, electron

My electron app is not displaying desktop notifications on windows 10. Mac and Linux are working fine.

I am using electron-packager to build.

Documentation says "On Windows 10, a shortcut to your app with an Application User Model ID must be installed to the Start Menu." so i call app.setAppUserModelId(myID) in main.js and i put a shortcut to the .exe inside C:\Users\sam\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs

Still no notifications. I'm not sure which step I am doing wrong.

Comment: Looks like there's an open [issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/10864) with the notifications & Windows 10. What version of Electron & Windows are you running?

Comment: I am running v2.0.8 for electron and 1803 windows enterprise build 17134.285

Answer (score 6):

I'm using [electron-builder](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder) and it works like a charm.

[Electron multiplatform notifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZq6Y.png)

I uploaded this code to my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/opolancoh/electron-multiplatform-notifications). It works on Windows, MacOS and Linux. If you want that notifications work on windows, you need to install the app running 'npm run dist'. It creates a folder called 'dist' where you can find the installer.

This is the important part:

```
app.on('ready', () => {
  if (process.platform === 'win32') {
    app.setAppUserModelId("com.ikobit.desktop-notifications");
  }

  ...
});
```

Comment: Perfect. The key point here is that you need to call `app.setAppUserModelId('com.yourcompany.yourapp');` when app.on('ready', func) fires. What a pain to find this out! Thanks for the WORKING example.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I was setting the app id in multiple locations. I also needed to install with electron-builder and then it worked.