# Notifications not working on Windows 10 - Electron JS

Tags: windows, electron, electron-packager

I was learning Electron and made a basic electron app and packaged it for windows. The app was not showing notifications so I followed the instructions [here](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/notifications)

> On Windows 10, a shortcut to your app with an Application User Model ID must be installed to the Start Menu. This can be overkill during development, so adding node_modules\electron\dist\electron.exe to your Start Menu also does the trick. Navigate to the file in Explorer, right-click and 'Pin to Start Menu'. You will then need to add the line app.setAppUserModelId(process.execPath) to your main process to see notifications.

I did as suggested here and the notifications started working. They were still working after packaging the app. So I wanted to check whether after a user uses an installer to install this app, the notifications would still work.

I don't have any experience with packaging software, and I used [InstallForge](https://installforge.net/) to make an installer. Turns out, after installing the app using the installer, the app still works but notifications don't, even after pinning the exe to start.

I tried copying the build folder (direct build, not the installer one) to another location and trying the same thing and it still works. This also works if I copy the installation folder to another location. But it does not work from inside `Program Files(x86)\myapp\appname\build\myapp.exe` so I am assuming this must be something about permissions, but I do not understand exactly what is happening. I have't checked the app yet on Linux so I don't know if I would face similar problems there as well.

Any pointers would be great, Thank you.

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53510850/2388129
The key is to set app.setAppUserModelId('com.yourcompany.yourapp'); when app.on('ready' fires. <ake sure that your appId is also in your package.json.

Comment: I'm on windows 10 and I did next: if (process.platform === 'win32') {
      app.setAppUserModelId("nl.youtubemuziekdownloaden.app");
    } 
and also called notification let myNotification = new Notification('Title', {
              body: 'Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet'
            })
            
            myNotification.onclick = () => {
              console.log('Notification clicked')
            }
in my package.json I placed: "build": {
    "appId": "nl.youtubemuziekdownloaden.app"
  },
It still DOES NOT WORK :(